# Delete value in array and in array Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have array

```
Product:[
     {
       content:'',
       tag:[
         {
           name:'a',
         },
         {
           name:'b'
         }
       ]
     }
]
```

And i have value `x = 'a'`

I need delete name in `tag` in array `product` where `name == x`

I used two foreach, one foreach loop Product and one foreach loop tag, then checking condition `if(name == x)` and delete item

**Code**

```
$tag = 'a'

foreach($blogs as $blog) {

    foreach(json_decode($blog->tag) as $detail_tag) {

        if($detail_tag == $tag) {

            delete($detail_tag);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I mean function have some error ( I write code on paper and I don't  test :( ) and I mean it no performance @@.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

- You need to first convert the JSON object to array using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function. Second parameter in this function is set to `true`, in order to convert the JSON into associative array.
- Then, loop over the array. In `foreach` you need to access key as well, in order to `unset()` the value.
- Then, convert the array back to JSON object using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function.

Try:

```
$tag = 'a';

foreach($blogs as $blog) {

  // convert to array using json_decode() (second parameter to true)
  $blog_arr = json_decode($blog->tag, true);

  // Loop over the array accessing key as well
  foreach( $blog_arr as $key => $detail_tag){

      if ($detail_tag === $tag) {
          // unset the key
          unset($blog_arra[$key]);
      }

   // Convert back to JSON object
   $blog_tag_modified = json_encode($blog_arr);
}
```